# Sprite Shearing in Directx

Tags: c++, directx, transform

When I shear the sprite in Directx 11, it shows this

```
*******     *******      <= fixed
*     *  =>  *     *
*******       *******
```

Here is not the result that I want

What I want is this

```
*******       *******
*     *  =>  *     *
*******     *******      <= fixed
```

PS. I am using XMMatrixOrthographicOffCenterLH to setup the camera

Comment: Not sure what API you are using to apply the shear. In general, if you are multiplying some sort of transformation matrices, a shear matrix generally keeps the middle fixed, you subsequently want to apply a shift to align the top or bottom edge.

Answer (score 2):

A shear transformation is basically the following: For an input position (p.x, p.y) add a part of the y-coordinate to the x-coordinate. So the result is: (p.x + s * p.y, p.y).

With that in mind, you should do what yiding suggested. First apply a transform that aligns the rectangle, do the shear and revert the first transform.

The easiest way is to translate by `spriteHeight` upwards and use a negative shear factor. So the transformation will be:

```
Translate(0, -spriteHeight, 0) * shearx(-s) * Translate(0, spriteHeight, 0)
```